# Why doesn't C++ string iterator check errors?

Tags: c++, error-handling, stl, iterator

I am an university student. I was given a task to write singly linked list. I started implementing it with nodes exposed([c# style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzf8sxa0(v=vs.110).aspx)), but it lead to many null checks when used. Then I made nodes private and list elements were exposed via an iterator([stl style](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/insert/)), so there are no null checks, but it is still necessary to check if iterator isn't at the end of the list. I want to write a good implementation, so I made a simple test to check how c++ STL handles some errors:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string first = "afasdasds";
  string second = "asdadas";
  int i = 0;
  for(auto it = first.begin(); i < 100; it++)
  {
    bool result = it > second.begin();
    cout << result;
    i++;
  }
}
```

It doesn't. It goes into infinite loop without i check.

1. Shouldn't iterator check whether comparison even makes sense? Clearly, comparing iterators from different lists should raise an error.
2. Shouldn't ++ operator check if it hasn't overflown? This code:

   ```
   using namespace std;
   int main()
   {
     string first = "afasdasds";
     for(auto it = first.begin();; it++)
     {
       cout << *it;
     }
   }
   ```

Prints part of memory and then segfaults. 
I think these error checks are reasonable. They also shouldn't be hard to write. Why weren't they implemented in STL and should they be? Would it be considered good code practice? I am still inexperienced, so it is hard for me to judge how "perfect" should the code be. Was this good moment to stop, or should we write error checks further?

Comment: No, it shouldn't - Part of the C++ design philosophy is that you don't pay for what you don't ask for explicitly. So checking whether an iterator is still in range is the programmers job

Comment: No there's no such requirement. It's up to the programmer to not go out of bounds.

Comment: Also the correct way to use `for` with iterators would be `for(auto it = first.begin(); it != first.end(); ++it)` - simple enough in my opinion

Comment: Arguably it should be `for (const auto &c : first)`.

Comment: What is `it > second.begin()` supposed to do?

Comment: It's not exactly what you asked for, but [this](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) is very related to what you are asking. Also check out [this](https://youtu.be/1QhtXRMp3Hg) if you have an hour or two.

Comment: *"Shouldn't ++ operator check if it hasn't overflown?"* - How could it? It's an iterator, that has no connection to the container it references. How should the iterator know, that it has been incremented past the end of a container?

Comment: @IInspectable: That's a bit of a chicken-and-egg problem. If the specification would have said that an iterator must check if the end is hit, it would have had a reference to the container. Mind you, that would make `splice` a problem to implement.

Comment: @MSalters: `container::end()` returns an iterator **value**. You wouldn't need a reference to the container to check against that value.

Comment: @UnholySheep or even `for (auto& char : first)` and then it's done under the hood :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Shouldn't iterator check whether comparison even makes sense?
>
> ...
>
> Shouldn't ++ operator check if it hasn't overflown?

So if I write my code correctly - and I mean *statically*, provably correct so that it logically cannot be wrong - do I still have to pay the runtime cost of all the code you added to detect your mistakes?

Your code is *supposed* to be correct. If your implementation does these checks and they *ever* detect a bug, that means your code was wrong in the first place. It's very useful to have tools that help you detect and fix your mistakes, but they're supposed to be debugging aids, not crutches.

> ... Clearly, comparing iterators from different lists should raise an error

Comparing iterators from different lists *should* raise an error: during code review.

Further, if the only way to avoid paying the runtime cost of these checks is to avoid using the standard library, lots of people will in fact have to avoid using the standard library, and there's limited benefit to having a standard library that people don't actually use.

Answer (score 3):

It is a trade off, performance verses safety.

Checks slow things down. For an iterator that can amount to a **lot** because they get incremented and dereferenced in tight loops.

Many implementations of the `STL` mitigate this by having *debug* and *release* versions of the library so you can run with checks during testing but release without the checks.

Regardless the essential philosophy of the `STL` encourages safer programming. If you think about it, iterators should always come from a safe place.

That is at the start of a process you obtain your iterators from either a call to the container's `begin()` or `end()` functions, or as a result returned from an *algorithm*, maybe `std::find` for example.

Also you can use safer constructs such as the [range based for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

**This style of programing helps keep the boundaries safe.**

The really dangerous stuff happens when you use *indexing* or *iterator offsets* which should be avoided if possible. Also storing iterators for later use is not very safe.

So **do** use iterators and **don't** use indexes (unless you have to). Try to avoid keeping iterators beyond their immediate use.

But, most of all, use the `DEBUG` version and **test, test, test** so that your boundary checks get done to a high degree of confidence.

Comment: Arguably, what helps a lot more than using debug versions of iterators and testing, testing, testing, is using contemporary C++ paradigms. In this case: range-based for loops.

Comment: @IInspectable Well I thought my answer covered that too but I could add some more on that.

Comment: Nope, sorry, nothing in your answer even touches upon the issue. It merely states what not to do. And range-based for loops, by coincidence, don't even allow you to do most (all?) of those things. But you never explicitly named that construct.

Comment: `test test *text*`?  Needs more testing ;)

Comment: @UKMonkey Thnx (I should pretend I did that on purpose to illustrate the point...)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is debugging and testing, for gcc you can use [debug containers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode_using.html) which are available as GNU extensions.

The 1st example could be rewritten using `__gnu_debug::string` instead of `std::string`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <debug/string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  __gnu_debug::string first = "afasdasds";
  __gnu_debug::string second = "asdadas";
  int i = 0;
  for(auto it = first.begin(); i < 100; it++)
  {
    bool result = it > second.begin();
    cout << result;
    i++;
  }
}
```

It is crashing with a rather clear error message:

```
$ ./a.out 
/usr/include/c++/7/debug/safe_iterator.h:658:
Error: attempt to order iterators from different sequences.

Objects involved in the operation:
    iterator "lhs" @ 0x0x7ffd4285a5e0 {
      type = __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, __gnu_debug::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > (mutable iterator);
      state = dereferenceable (start-of-sequence);
      references sequence with type '__gnu_debug::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >' @ 0x0x7ffd4285a650
    }
    iterator "rhs" @ 0x0x7ffd4285a690 {
      type = __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, __gnu_debug::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > (mutable iterator);
      state = dereferenceable (start-of-sequence);
      references sequence with type '__gnu_debug::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >' @ 0x0x7ffd4285a610
    }
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: And this debug output is particularly useful because it also shows something the OP wasn't even asking about, which is the invalid comparison between iterators of totally unrelated "containers".